# can't use a field of the database in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a database like this:

```
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, default=None)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, default=None)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, blank=False, default=None)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, default=None)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

in `views.py` I want to send a `user` that currently logged in and show its informations from DB at template.
my `views.py`:

```
user = User.objects.filter(email=request.POST['email'])
#some code ....
context = RequestContext(request, {
    'user': user[0]
})
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

my template :

```
{% if user %}
    Wellcome {{ user.firstName }}
{% endif %}
```

but I don't see anything after `welcome`.also when I use this:

```
{% if user %}
    Wellcome {{ user }}
{% endif %}
```

I see `welcome anonymousUser` where I am wrong ?

Comment: use a different name. Something like `user_obj` and try .

Comment: thanks.you are right.please add your comment as answer.very very thanks.but what is user that cause conflict ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `user` as the context variable, as it conflicts with the `user` object that is injected into the context by the processor

```
django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth
```

Now, to fix your issue, rename `user` to `user_obj` or something which makes more sense.

Read [more here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the behavior you are describing you are likely not getting any objects returned from the call to filter:

```
user = User.objects.filter(email=request.POST['email'])
```

I would look at the value that is returned from `request.POST['email']` and making sure that value is in your datbase as the starting point.

Also, you should be aware that the filter function returns a [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) and not a User object. If you want to retrieve a unique User object you can use the [get function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) instead.

Comment: no. this query return an object I test it when debug.I edit my code so `user[0]` will be an user object that has `firstName`

Comment: Can you post the output of the debugging?

Comment: I only add `print user[0].firstName` after the line `user = User.objects.filter(email=request.POST['email'])` then I see the firstName of the user in terminal.